# Задачка на С++ про строки

Tags: c++, строки

Всем привет, сейчас решаю задачу но она проходит только 8/14 тестов. Я просто не могу понять где моя ошибка( Может кто-то из опытных программистов сможет найти случаи где программа работает не коректно.
Ссылку на тестирующею систему к сожалению дать не могу, она закрыта. Файлов с тестами там тоже нет

---

***Дано выражение одно из следующих видов: «A+B», «A-B» или «A*B», где A и B - целые числа от 0 до 109. Определите значение этого выражения.***

ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ

**Программа получает на вход одну строку описанного вида.**

ВЫХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ

**Программа должна вывести целое число — результат вычисления данного выражения.**

ПРИМЕР

**ввод**    2*2
**вывод**
4

### **ввод**
100-101
**вывод**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


long long perevod(string n) { // перевод строки в число
    int temp = 0; 
    int i = 0;
    while (n[i] >= 0x30 && n[i] <= 0x39)
    {
        temp = temp + (n[i] & 0x0F);
        temp = temp * 10;
        i++;
    }
    temp = temp / 10;
    return(temp);
}


int main() {
    char znak;
    znak = 0;
    string s, chislo_1, chislo_2;
    getline(cin, s);
    int i = 0;
    while (isalnum(s[i])) //беру первое число
    {
        chislo_1.push_back(s[i]);
        i++;
        
    }
    i = 1;
    s.erase(0, chislo_1.size());
    while (isalnum(s[i])) //беру второе число
    {
        chislo_2.push_back(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    znak = s[0]; //беру знак
    
    if (znak == '+') // в зависимости от знака делаю действие 
    {
        cout << perevod(chislo_1) + perevod(chislo_2);
    }
    else if (znak == '-')
    {
        cout << perevod(chislo_1) - perevod(chislo_2);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << perevod(chislo_1) * perevod(chislo_2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Уточните заголовок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот уж воистину, зачем просто, если можно сложно...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int a, b;
    char c;
    cin >> a >> c >> b;
    switch(c)
    {
    case '+': a+=b; break;
    case '-': a-=b; break;
    case '*': a*=b; break;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вау, что-то я очень сильно загнался, а всё гениальное просто